# Regular Expression over multiple lines (Search+Replace)

Tags: regex

Im trying to search and replace parts of a huge xml file and am stuck with getting a correct regular expression for something like this

```
<Start id="AUTO_TEXT"...>
    MORE TEXT
    MORE TEXT
</Start>
```

I always end up writing something like this, which isn't working:

```
<Start id="AUTO_[^/r]*<\/Start>
```

What am I missing?

Oh, I'm using EditPad Pro which uses the "The Just Great Software Regular Expression Engine" (Wow, what a name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in EditPadPro:

```
(?s)<Start id="AUTO.*?</Start>
```

**Explanation**

- `(?s)` activates `DOTALL` mode, allowing the dot to match across lines
- The star quantifier in `.*?` is made "lazy" by the `?` so that the dot only matches as many characters as needed to allow the next token to match (shortest match).

**Option 2**

Instead of using `(?s)`, you can also press the `Dot` toggle in the search bar.

[image: EPP]

Comment: thanks to you:) I love RegExpressions since they are so powerful yet always end up forgetting the syntax...